# I want a div element to come from bottom

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, popup

I want a div to be popup when click on that button. The div should appears from bottom to top and also it should not affect the overall page content. I set the button properties to fixed because it should. Please help to solve this problem. I will be so greatfull! Thank You!

```js
$('#sec-menu').click(function() {
  $('.sec-menu-div').toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.sec-menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 777;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: chartreuse;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.sec-menu button {
  padding: 5px 50px;
}

.sec-menu-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 777;
  color: white;
  background-color: darkgoldenrod;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transform: translateX(1000%);
}

.sec-menu-div.active {
  bottom: 29px;
  z-index: 777;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sec-menu">
  <button id="sec-menu">Menu</button>
  <div class="sec-menu-div">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente, eligendi.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the element appear from the bottom of the page instead of the right side, change `translateX` to `translateY` in both classes.

You will also need to amend the `left` position and `width` of the element to meet your exact use case - in this example I left it in the centre of the page.

```js
$('#sec-menu').click(function() {
  $('.sec-menu-div').toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.sec-menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 777;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: chartreuse;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.sec-menu button {
  padding: 5px 50px;
}

.sec-menu-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 777;
  color: white;
  background-color: darkgoldenrod;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transform: translateY(1000%);
}

.sec-menu-div.active {
  bottom: 29px;
  z-index: 777;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sec-menu">
  <button id="sec-menu">Menu</button>
  <div class="sec-menu-div">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente, eligendi.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer! Im so greatfull to you. One little problem is i want same moving effect when it is going back to bottom. It should not disappear in micro seconds.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I'd suggest starting a new question about the additional transition.

Comment: Sure! I will raise a new question.